# generate headers for webm file to play downloaded corrupted media

Tags: javascript, specifications, w3c, webm, media-source

there is a website that fetches some .webm files from their server, some are what appears to be chunks of the file, the more it plays, others appear to be some form of the complete webm file.

However, when attempting to play any of these files in a custom video element or any other vide player, it is either just black, or white, or doesn't play.

**I think it has to do with incomplete headers**

I suspect that the host website downloads some kind of chunk of the video from the server, then somehow appends the webm headers separately in order play it in their own player

The thing is, I want to be able to play (and eventually download) a fully operational .webm file, based on the other corrupted webm files, and I *suspect* the way to do this is to write some custom .webm headers and append them to the beginning of the video, and this is where I need some help.

I'm aware there is the [WebM Specification](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/webm-byte-stream-format.html#webm-init-segments), I just don't know how to use it with client-side JavaScript to accomplish what I need here, or if this is even the right kind of solution, because I've also heard of the [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) API, which I also suspect is used for this (website is [here](https://jem.tv/erev-shavuos-5742))

Comment: I have files without the header. Did you find a way to easily add a header?

Comment: @john he's banned or suspended

Comment: @John I asked ChatGPT to write a intricate WebM VP8 encoder with pure JavaScript and the uint8array class and got an idea of the headers and other things

Comment: Did it work? Let me know if it worked out.

Comment: @john here's the quite lengthy discussion where I tried to convince it to explain in depth the WebM and vorbis encoding process in simple JavaScript here  https://awtsmoos.com/indexOfFiles.html currently it's the one that says "WebM and vorbis encoding. Html" something, towards the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to obtain each part of the webm files. Just adjust the interval parameter, at the end of the request, and download the complete file.

For example:
https://r1---sn-b8u-nn5l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?...&range=0-76746&...
...&range=76746-183717&...
...&range=398277-751324&...
...&range=751325-1387287&...

You just need change the start and final range to get the part you wish
...&range=0-1387287&...

Comment: Is the range get header supported on all servers or just Google

Comment: I think only Google Works this way. I am not sure.